# Integrating a player youtube api v3 in air desktop application

Tags: actionscript-3, air, youtube-api

I try to integrate a youtube player in a air application.
I use the demo code for a simple test.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/flash_api_reference#Examples

But it don't work for me.

**The first error was**

> SecurityError: Error #3207: Application-sandbox content cannot access
>   this feature.

I put

```
Security.allowDomain("www.youtube.com");
```

in a try/catch. That solve this first error.

**Sadly I'm blocked whith a second error**

> *** Security Sandbox Violation *** SecurityDomain 'http://s.ytimg.com/yts/swfbin/player-vflBOCKzZ/apiplayer3.swf' tried
>   to access incompatible context

I add a LoaderContext

```
var context:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
    context.checkPolicyFile = true;
    context.applicationDomain = ApplicationDomain.currentDomain;
    context.allowCodeImport = true;
```

but that don't solve the problem.

Is anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

i used following code in start and it worked for me

try {Security.allowDomain("*");}catch (e) { };